# Create binding for 2 dependent static libraries in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have an issue with binding on Xamarin.iOS.

I have 2 libraries:
libA.a
libB.a

And libB.a is depend on libA.a classes. In **libA** I have this class:

```
namespace ABC {
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface ClassAbc {
        [Export ("setString:")]
        void SetString (string abc);
    }
}
```

And in **libB** I have this code:

```
namespace ABCUsage {
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface ClassAbcUsage {
        [Export ("setAbc:")]
        void SetAbc (ClassAbc abc);
    }
}
```

I have no source code of libA.a and libB.a but only universal static libraries and headers.

I tried to add libA binding project and final A.dll as a Reference for libB binding but it says "namespace ABC not found".

How should I make a correct binding for libB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello you can bind as many libraries as you want in a single binding project, just make sure you specify fully qualified type names

```
namespace ABC {
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface ClassAbc {
        [Export ("setString:")]
        void SetString (string abc);
    }
}

namespace ABCUsage {
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface ClassAbcUsage {
        [Export ("setAbc:")]
        void SetAbc (ABC.ClassAbc abc);
                    //^^^^^
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OMG! It works. I can't even imagine that I can add several static libraries to on binding project. Thank you!

Comment: @dalexsoto, this is a great answer, indeed! However, even though it’s been almost five years, lol can you also answer what is the app flow in context of those two libraries connection? I mean, if we call some code from the library one, which requires accessing some methods from the library two (from its native code), how would all that work?..

Comment: @Agat It should work as is if they are static libraries, since the native linker should figure this one out and keep the objects around unless the native library is resolving stuff dynamically. Of course bot native static libraries should be added into the same binding project.

Comment: @dalexsoto, both static libraries were converted from *.framework by Sharpie. So, seems, like it's ok? But what I am trying to clarify for sure: I can add two *.a files into one Binding project, and the builder (linker) would figure out everything itself? I mean, if one of the *.a file refers the second one? (I mean, on native level).